# What is the right SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, filter, syntax, opencart

What is the right sql syntax? I want to filter for 4 id.

```
$sql .= " AND order_status_id = '22''20''24''23'";
```

Now, Im only see the order_status_id 22.

Comment: You can use in operator. AND order_status_id in ('22','20','24','23');

Comment: I'm surprised that the script you ran didn't even end in a syntax error

Comment: @Kisleves, it's good that you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting an answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left of the answer. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Comment: don't put numbers in single quotes `IN (22,20,24,23)`

Comment: @MalcolmSalvador: Kisleves is probably using MySQL which is known to run even wildly invalid SQL statements without complaints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for several values  you could use the IN  operator

```
 AND order_status_id IN ('22','20','24','23')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use IN operator.

```
AND order_status_id in ('22','20','24','23');
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query is very helpful for you.

```
$sql .= " AND order_status_id IN ('22','20','24','23') ";
```